# Pipe streamReader to streamWriter

Tags: c#, stream

I would like to read data from streamReader and send this data to streamWriter.

Exists a way to pipe streams elegantly?

```cs
var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(randomStream1);
var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(randomStream2);

// how to do this?
PipeReaderToWriter(streamReader, streamWriter, cancelationToken);
```

Comment: What is the goal in doing this? At a lower level (raw streams, not streams being treated as text as we are here) there is `CopyTo` and `CopyToAsync`. I suppose you could take the `.BaseStream` property from each, but I guess you're maybe doing this to change encoding or something?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, I would like to write a simple c# network proxy. I want to pipe both `NetworkStream`, the listener and the client network stream, one to each other.

Comment: Hmm. Well, `CopyTo` on the base thread would be blocking, so you couldn't also copy the other way. It might be best to use `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` both ways and then stream the data like that. But it's certainly not the elegant solution that you desire. I'm honestly not sure, sorry.

Comment: Also, `CopyTo` looks like it stops when there are no more available bytes. So you may have to write your own thing to do your piping.  In any case, StreamReader/Writers are for text and should most likely not be used for binary streams like networkStream.